# Как вернуть значение?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Мне нужно вернуть значение r. Что я делаю не так? И как сделать чтобы работало? Если вместо return r написать console.log(r), то в консоль выводит. Спасибо за внимание.

```
var vk = {
  api: function(method, options) {
    var v = '';
    url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/' + method + '?' + options + '&v=5.52&' + token;
    httpGet(url, function(r) {
      return r
    });
  }
}

function httpGet(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

console.log(vk.api('audio.get'))
```

Comment: асинхронность...

Comment: `callback(JSON.parse( xhr.responseText));` - куда попадает return изнутри callback?

Comment: @Igor  не знаю, это весь код который я написал. js изучаю совсем недавно и многого не понимаю.